# Shutdown Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

How to shutdown completely windows 8, because this "shutdown" command only hibernates , and some programs just don't like it, and don't run until I restart the pc...   is there a way to change the "shutdown" function for it to really shutdown the pc (like the restart function already does) ?

Comment: Are you asking how to programatically shutdown windows? If so, please add a tag to indicate what language you are using, and post your current code. If not, this question is off-topic and should be posted to SuperUser.com

Comment: There should be three options for you when you click the power button: Restart, Sleep and shutdown. Shutdown works exactly the way its supposed to. Not exactly sure what you are describing there. Sleep works as "hibernate".

Comment: See answers to [How do I shutdown Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/491008/how-do-i-shutdown-windows-8), [Software shutdown does not work in Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/502923/software-shutdown-does-not-work-in-windows-8) and *many* more questions posted by people who couldn't locate the shutdown button anymore in Win8, or were confused by the new Fast Startup/Hybrid Boot options. A shortcut to shutdown.exe will do what you want, or you can turn it off as detailed [here](http://superuser.com/questions/508050/difference-between-shutting) and [here](http://goo.gl/LZm4f).

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel > Power Options > Change what the power buttons do

Under 'Shutdown settings'

Uncheck 'Turn on fast start-up'

Answer (score 0):

For the -real- shutdown run CMD (as admin) then "shutdown /s /t 2".  Leave out the quotes, of course. The "/S" tells the computer to completely power off. The "/t 2" is the delay before shutdown begins. You can change the delay time to nearly any number of seconds you want.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to disable hybrid shutdown which is the author's question.